# How to make sure one time running quartz job will be executed even if server is not up at that time?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have a situation that specific quartz job must execute only once at specific time of day.
I want to know if there is a workaround to make sure this job will be executed even if server for any reason does not up and running at that point of time.
If i switch from ramjobstore to database does this guaranty the mentioned problem?

EDIT:
To make things clear i use the @Vala. D comment:

> if the server was down at this time to run it immediately after server-start

This behavior will cover my requirements

Comment: so ... a job is deployed on server X. You need the job to execute even if server X is down. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Add to your scheduled job a persisted bool flag which is getting set, when the task was run. And add an additional task which triggers at startup, which checks according to the flag and the current date if the task should ran in the past and wasn't already. Watch out for concurrency.

Comment: @Vala.D. why is al that needed? the result would be to have it run on a time it's not specified, but "the first available slot"

Comment: @Stultuske
Yes, that's right

Comment: @MohsenVahedi you understand that that is not possible? unless, of course, you have a backup server, which is up and running at that time

Comment: @Stultuske I don't know of a possibility within Quarz to do what OP is looking for. I just described how i would build such a solution. And my solution would not require a backup server.

Comment: @Vala.D. indeed, it wouldn't, but then the service would not execute at the specified time, so it doesn't meet the requirements. If the server isn't running, services that run on said server don't run, it's that simple. I'm not saying your solution isn't good, it just doesn't meet the (impossible) requirements imo

Comment: I understood that OP wants to run a task at a given time and if the server was down at this time to run it immediately after server-start.

Comment: not how I read it, but that's something the OP will need to clarify

Comment: "will be execute it" doesn't imply to be executed immediately.

Comment: I agree with you that if the server is not running it is impossible to act at this given time.

Comment: @Vala.D. I updated the question